# Why a function with Bool argument accepts String?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function which accepts an bool as an argument:

```
void func(bool a)
{
    doing something;
}
```

But when I'm calling the function and passed string to it:

```
func("false");
```

Actually it should accept only.

```
func(false);
```

It accepts string without any error.

why?

Comment: Pointer will be implicitly converted to bool. Null pointer -> false, Non-null pointer -> true. In this case, func will receive a *true* value from the non-null "false" string in const char* type.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall OK, I've re-post it.

Comment: is there any way by which I can explicitly make it to accept boolean

Comment: Scan the string and interpret it to bool by code. Maybe like strcmp(str, "false") == 0 or scanf("%d", &bResult); ...

Comment: Thanks for help :-)

Comment: i think the explicit keyword could help: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Literal string is a char pointer, and pointer will be implicitly converted to bool.

- Null pointer -> `false`
- Non-null pointer -> `true`

In this case, the *func* will receive a `true` value from the non-null *"false"* string , which is `const char*` type.

You may need an interpreter function to able to read "false", "0", "no", etc from keyboard typing and convert to bool false which the program can understand.

Comment: True, we use `if (p) { ... }` to determine if a pointer equals to `NULL` or not in C/C++ all the time.

Comment: String literal is not a pointer. But it does implicitly convert to a pointer, just like the pointer implicitly converts to boolean.

Answer (score 4):

According to the C++ standard *§4.14/p1 Boolean conversions [conv.bool]* (**Emphasis Mine**):

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, **pointer**, or pointer to
>   member type **can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. A zero value,
>   null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to
>   false; any other value is converted to true.** For direct-initialization
>   (8.6), a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be converted to a prvalue
>   of type bool; the resulting value is false.

That is, according the C++ standard, conversion from a string literal (i.e., pointer) to a boolean is a standard conversion and thus what you're experiencing is perfectly normal/standard language behavior.

You can restrict your function to explicitly accept only bool values by defining a generic overload of your function as deleted:

```
template<typename T> void func(T&&) = delete;

void func(bool a) {
  // do something...
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c0cba9b4ae0d858)

Answer (score 2):

Pointers can be implicitly converted to `bool`; The value is `false`, if the pointer is `NULL`, and it is `true` if the pointer is `!NULL`. Hence, since you pass a pointer to `char *`-literal `"false"`, this pointer is `! NULL` and yields `true`. See the following definition in the [cpp reference concerning of implicit conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

> Boolean conversions
>
> A prvalue of integral, floating-point, unscoped
> enumeration, pointer, and pointer-to-member types can be converted to
> a prvalue of type bool. The value zero (for integral, floating-point,
> and unscoped enumeration) and the null pointer and the null
> pointer-to-member values become false. All other values become true

Answer (score 1):

@101010's answer is good. But for the benefit of those with older compilers (which I suspect do not accept that syntax), there is an alternative approach.

First:
A template function *declaration* with no *definition/implementation*. That way, if you call it accidentally with `func("false")` or `func('y')` or `func(0)` (an int), the linker will complain. Which will make you look for the problem.

```
template<typename T> void func(T a);  // prototype only
```

Declare this alongside your real `void func(bool a)` function.

If you have this inside a class, you can make the template function/method private, which will make the error into a compiler error (easier to understand, but if the accidental mis-typed call comes from within a class or friend, it will still be a linker error).